# "\xED" followed by "t" on UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, codificação-de-caracteres, devise

Tenho uma aplicação rails e quando vou executar ou compilar os assets dá o seguinte erro:

```
"\ xED" followed by "t" on UTF-8
```

No meu

> application.rb

já tenho essa chave:

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Pode colocar aqui o log completo do erro?

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, eu já achei o erro. Era um elemento dentro de um arquivo js que estava com a codificação errada. Infelizmente o log do erro nao é especifico em qual arquivo estava, então tive que olhar vários arquivos para achar.